# The return value of a function MPI

Tags: c++, linux, mpi

I run a function in which every process enters. Some calculations are made and then all the process exit from that function but only process with rank 0 returns something. The problem is that at the return statement, the value is correct but in main, where I assign the result of the function, the return value is 0. Here some piece of code:

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
CCI = TestKNN (tlist, data, true, mode, false, false);      
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

.......

```
TestKNN(....)
{
    int res; 
    if (rank == 0)
    {
          res = 0;
          send data to each process and receive result
          receive result from every process
          res += return_value
    }
    else
    {
         receive data
         work on data
         send result to rank 0
    }

    if (rank == 0)
         return res
 }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: is it possible that you are not waiting for the results after sending the data?

Comment: I make a MPI_Receive from every process and after every receive I increment the variable. Just before return I make an MPI_Barrier(). I print the value just before return and it's correct but in main it returns 0.

Comment: A lot of things could be the problem.  It's very difficult to attempt to address an MPI problem without seeing any MPI code.  How do we debug "send data" and "receive result"?

Comment: Why not use `MPI_Reduce`?